# android - Programmatically refresh (draw, erase, and update) shapes on custom View in background asynchoronously wihtout blocking the UI

Tags: android, view, drawing, custom-view

Below is the **CustomView** class extending the **View** class. It works good statically.

I am clicking a button, it shows the targeted shelf, which I am headed to. Then I am clicking another button, it clears the targeted shelf and the map is back in its initial state.

What needs to be done is, this baby has to clear the targeted shelf by itself using some async calls, after *xx* seconds. And in the same fashion, when I begin to show my position on the map with an "**X**", it has to refresh that "**X**" while I am walking.

The **AsyncTask** doesn't seem to be the perfect solution for this. Do *you* have an idea on how the map should update itself?

Thanks in advance.

The **CustomView**:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    ShapeDrawable roomFrame, targetShelfFrame, me;
    int halfMe;
    ArrayList<ShapeDrawable> shelfFrames;
    //(...)

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(roomFrame != null)
            roomFrame.draw(canvas);
        for (ShapeDrawable shelfFrame : shelfFrames)
            shelfFrame.draw(canvas);
        if(targetShelfFrame != null)
            targetShelfFrame.draw(canvas);
        if(me != null)
            me.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room){
        roomFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        roomFrame.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        roomFrame.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        roomFrame.setBounds(10, 10, room.getWidth(), room.getHeight());
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setShelves(ArrayList<Shelf> shelves){
        shelfFrames = new ArrayList<ShapeDrawable>();
        for(int i = 0; i<shelves.size(); i++){
            ShapeDrawable shelfFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            shelfFrame.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
            shelfFrame.setBounds(shelves.get(i).getXPosition(), shelves.get(i).getYPosition(), shelves.get(i).getWidth(), shelves.get(i).getHeight());
            shelfFrames.add(shelfFrame);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTargetShelf(Shelf shelf){
        targetShelfFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        targetShelfFrame.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        targetShelfFrame.setBounds((int)(shelf.getXPosition()), (int)(shelf.getYPosition()),
                (int)((shelf.getXPosition() + shelf.getWidth())), 
                (int)((shelf.getYPosition() + shelf.getHeight())));
        invalidate();
    }

    public void clearTargetShelf(){
        targetShelfFrame = null;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void updateMyPosition(Position position){
        me = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        me.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);
        me.setBounds(position.getX() - halfMe, position.getY() - halfMe, 
            position.getX() + halfMe, position.getY() + halfMe);
    }
}
```

How I call it:

```
public void loadRoomPlan(Room room, ArrayList<Shelf> shelves){
    CustomView exampleView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.roomplan);
    exampleView.setRoom(room);
    exampleView.setShelves(shelves);
}
```

Comment: Btw, I have read about Handler, Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor, FutureTask, Future, Callable, Runnable, and a lot of stuff about Threads and Processes. And yes. I am unbelievably confused.

Comment: **Definition for the map**: This View itself is a map (it is a room and has shelves in it). And the person holding this hand-held device is walking in the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the easiest way (as far as I understand your goals) to solve your problem is to use Handler to perform a delayed execution on a UI thread.
So what you need to do is:

- Create Handler (globally for your custom view)
- use `postDelayed(Runnable, long)` interface to run your shelf clean-up with certain delay

Your code would look like:

**The CustomView:**

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    ShapeDrawable roomFrame, targetShelfFrame;
    ArrayList<ShapeDrawable> shelfFrames;
    Handler uiThread = new Handler();
    //(...)

    public void setTargetShelf(final Shelf shelf){
        targetShelfFrame = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        targetShelfFrame.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        targetShelfFrame.setBounds((int)(shelf.getXPosition()), (int)(shelf.getYPosition()),
            (int)((shelf.getXPosition() + shelf.getWidth())), 
            (int)((shelf.getYPosition() + shelf.getHeight())));
        invalidate();
        uiThread.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                clearTargetShelf(shelf);            
            }
        }, 10000); //10 secs delay
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question (with walking 'X' on a map) I didn't quite understand - what type of map are you using? Is it google map? Is it your own map? What does 'walking' mean? Is it real movement, or just some sort of game where you can move your character on the map? Please clarify

Comment: (...) This view is actually a small map, from my point of view (It is a room and has shelves in it). Walking is real movement of me walking with the device in the hand. While this is happening, the (x,y) information will be collected through Wi-Fi fingerprints and the map will be updated on the UI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried first part, works great, thanks again. As of the second part, it doesn't seem that it should be solved this way. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, for the second part you need to do some other things. Is this view responsible for drawing 'X'? I don't see this in your `onDraw` method. Or you are planning to implement this? If so - I think you need to implement drawing logic for your current position within `onDraw()` method. So you need to track your current location and if deviation is greater than certain threshold - update position on a map. It is hard to create some code example for you because you need to implement some logic to translate GPS coordinates to coordinates on your map. This is very specific task

Comment: Pavel, I didn't have it implemented yet but I did it quickly (without an X but with an O). Everything about location etc is another topic but this baby now can show where I am on the map. I just need to call it from the main Activity periodically. (I sense that I need to do things with GPS BroadCastReceivers and like update the View as soon as a new BroadCast is received etc, but as I said, I will jump from that cliff later.)

Comment: in case you think my answer solves your problem - please mark it as answer. Otherwise - let me know if you need more assistance

Comment: What I would do is - I would move drawing logic to this view (some function called `drawMyLocation()`) and call it whenever `onDraw` happens for your custom view. Your location drawer would use gps coordinates which would be updated by listening to events from GPS. In this way you can get smooth movement on a map

Comment: Ok, thank you very much again. I am moving to that other cliff now.